# Proof that you can approximate any continuous function using rectangles/step functions within a small error

Tags: calculus, approximation, rectangles, step-function

Proof that rectangles or a combination of step functions can approximate any continuous function within a small $\epsilon$ which represents the error between the approximate step function and continuous function.

Does such a proof exists? Or combination of proofs? I'm trying to write a mathematical proof that neural networks can approximate any continuous function within a small epsilon because they can create a Riemann sum of any finite small size and therefore can approximate a continuous function.

Comment: What is epsilon measuring?  The maximum absolute difference between the original function and the step function?  The integral of the difference between the original function and the step function?  Or something else?

Comment: The error between the actual function and the step functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Now, subdivide the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length, with $n$ sufficiently large such that $\frac1n<\delta$. Then take $g$ to be the piecewise constant function defined by
$$
g(x)=f([nx]/n).
$$
I claim that
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Indeed, for $x\in[\frac{k}n,\frac{k+1}n)$ with $k=0,1,\ldots,n$, we have $[nx]/n=k/n$, and so
$$
|f(x)-g(x)|=|f(x)-f([nx]/n)|=|f(x)-f(k/n)|<\varepsilon,
$$
since $|x-\frac{k}n|<\delta$.

Comment: is there a name to this theorem or is it a proof you've conjectured?

Comment: It's a standard result. I don't know any name. I came up with this proof but anybody who has taken elementary analysis can come up with it easily. Note that I did not conjecture it. "Conjecture" means you are not sure if it works.