# Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous and take any $\epsilon>0$ . Construct a step function $T$ on $[a.b]$ with..

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous and take any $\epsilon>0$ . Construct a step function $T$ on $[a,b]$ with $|f(x)-T(x)|< \varepsilon, \,\, \forall x \in [a,b]$ .

**My approach:**

**(1)** Since $f$ is continuous and on a compact domain, we know that the Heine-Cantor theorem holds:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \ \ \exists \delta > 0 \ \ \ \forall x,y \in [a,b]:|x-y|< \delta \ \ \to |f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon$

This tells us that for any $\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \ \ \exists \delta >0 \ \ \ \forall x,y \in [a,b]:x\in \mathcal U_{\delta}(y) \to f(x) \in \mathcal U_{\varepsilon}(f(y))$

**(2)** Since the domain is compact the Heine-Borel theorem holds:

Every open cover of $[a,b]$ has a finite subcover.

This means hence: $\forall \varepsilon>0:\bigcup\limits_{x\in[a,b]} \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x)$ is a open cover of the domain $[a,b]$ there exists a $m \in \Bbb N$ so that:

$\bigcup\limits_{\mu=1}^m \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_\mu)$ is a cover of the whole domain $[a,b]$

Now we define our step function $T_{\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$:

$T_{\varepsilon}:[a,b] \to \Bbb R:x \mapsto T_{\varepsilon}(x):=\begin{cases}
  f(x_1),  & \text{for }x\in \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_1)\,\cap [a,b] \\
f(x_2),  & \text{für }x\in \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_2)\,\cap [a,b]\setminus \bigcup\limits_{\mu=1}^1 \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_{\mu})\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots\\
  f(x_m), & \text{for }x\in \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_m)\ \cap [a,b]\setminus \bigcup\limits_{\mu=1}^{m-1} \mathcal U_{\delta_{\varepsilon}}(x_\mu)
\end{cases}$

Now for any $\varepsilon >0 $ we know because of **(1)** that $|f(x)-T_{\varepsilon}(x)|< \epsilon$,

since $\forall x \in \mathcal U_\delta(x_m) \ \ \to f(x) \in \mathcal U_{\varepsilon}(f(x_m))$

It would be great if someone could check if this works :)

Comment: [A shorter proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593951/266110) if it interests you.

Comment: This is a weaker version of the weierstrass approximation theorem

Comment: I did not learn about that yet :)

Comment: @Pankaj Tiwari What is the connection to the Weierstrass approximation theorem? In that statement, we approximate by polynomials, here by step functions. Unless there is a trivial way to show that polynomials can be approximated by step functions (without solving the prblem in this post), I cannot see why any of the two statements would be weaker than the other.

Comment: Well "weak" not in the usual sense I guess. Maybe it's not the right word. But my point was that in both cases, you're approximating continuous functions via piecewise smooth functions. In OP's case, they are certain line segments joined together, in Weierstrass theorem, they are polynomials.